# Mix nVidia with ATI for 3 monitor setup?

Tags: display, multiple-monitors, amd-radeon, nvidia-geforce

I am currently working with 2 Monitors and a nVidia GTX560 Ti on an Asus p8p67 motherboard.

Because one of my old monitors is kind of crap, I was wondering if I could buy a new one and setup the old as 3rd monitor.
I read that nVidia cards only support 2 monitors so I figured I would buy an additional cheap ATI card like the HD 6670 for the 2nd and 3rd monitor. I don't want to use them for gaming, just watching videos and surfing. Is that possible?
I read something about physx getting disabled if I combine ATI and nVidia. Is this true if I use them seperately like I plan to?

Is that the best way to achieve such a setup? I don't want to spend too much money which I also could be spending on a better monitor.

Comment: I've removed the request for a suggestion for a new monitor - since its off topic for SU. Our chat, root access is a good place to ask, however.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, you haven't mentioned your OS.

Firstly, if you're running vista or better, you should be able to run different drivers for different cards - which makes what you want possible - this won't work on XP I suspect.

PhyX should work if you set your nvidia card as the primary display driver (as you should) and use the AMD card as the secondary - phyx works beautifully with the builtin intel video adaptor as the secondary adaptor on a ivy bridge box - I use a 660 as a primary adaptor and it handles phyx on borderlands 2 at maximum settings.

What you have in mind should work fine, assuming your PSU has the power to power two cards. You can probably go with nearly *any* supported video card for this, so going with the cheapest option may work here.

Comment: I am using Win 7. My PSU has 650W so I think it will be fine with an additional low-end card. Thanks for your help :)